# Unable to return Appsync @belongsTo bi-directional data

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create a bi-directional relationship in my Graphql schema with Appsync. I'm unable to figure out exactly how to return data using @belongsTo for my Sources model.

One of the issues is that I do not have the primary key for Sources stored in the Codes model that can be defined as the field for the @belongsTo directive, so if I do not define the primary key as the field, it returns null.

My ultimate goal is to see the source data in the Codes model.

Here's my schema:

```
type Codes
@model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, provider: oidc }
      { allow: public, provider: apiKey }
    ]
  )
  @searchable {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  createdAt: String!
  client: String!
    @index(
      name: "codes-client-index"
      queryField: "codesByClient"
      sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
    )
  code: String!
    @index(
      name: "sources-code-index"
      sortKeyFields: ["source"]
      queryField: "sourceByCode"
    )
  codes: String! @index(name: "codes-code-index", queryField: "codesByCode")
  source: String
    @index(
      name: "bySource"
      sortKeyFields: ["code"]
      queryField: "codesBySource"
    )
  sources: Sources @belongsTo
}

type Sources
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, provider: oidc }
      { allow: public, provider: apiKey }
    ]
  )
  @searchable {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  createdAt: String!
  client: String!
    @index(
      name: "source-client-index"
      queryField: "sourceByClient"
      sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"]
    )
  category: Category
  channel: String
  source: String
  from_goop: Boolean
  codes: [Codes] @hasMany(indexName: "bySource", fields: ["source"])
}
```